# SQLite not recording values after successful transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite

I'm having this weird situation about inserting a record in a table with autoincrement.

Here is the table:

```
String CREATE_TABLE_ROUTES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ROUTES +
                "(" +
                PK_ROUTE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                FK_ROUTE_TRACK_ID + " INTEGER," +
                COL_ROUTE_ORDER + " INTEGER(11)," +
                COL_ROUTE_LAT + " FLOAT," +
                COL_ROUTE_LONG + " FLOAT," +
                COL_ROUTE_TIME + " FLOAT," +
                COL_ROUTE_SPEED + " FLOAT," +
                COL_ROUTE_TIME_MS + " INTEGER(3)" +
                ")";
```

This is my insert method that is not working:

```
public void updateRoute(LatLongTime latLongTime, long track_id) {

        long route_id = -2;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();

        try {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(FK_ROUTE_TRACK_ID, track_id);
            values.put(COL_ROUTE_ORDER, getLastOrderForTrack(track_id) + 1); 
            values.put(COL_ROUTE_LAT, latLongTime.getLatitude());
            values.put(COL_ROUTE_LONG, latLongTime.getLongitude());
            values.put(COL_ROUTE_SPEED, latLongTime.getSpeed());
            values.put(COL_ROUTE_TIME, latLongTime.getInstante());

            route_id = db.insert(TABLE_ROUTES, null, values);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR Recording: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Log.d(TAG, "Route inserted: " + route_id + " track id: " + track_id);
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

Debbuging it I got a successful transaction, but after this method is called again, the same route_id is generated by the insert method.
Nothing is recorded after the code runs (with no exception).

This is what I get when I call this function several time at the debug:

> D/Database: Route inserted: 9362 track: 103
>   D/Database: Route inserted: 9362 track: 103
>   D/Database: Route inserted: 9362 track: 103

What I find most weird is that if I use ctrl+U (Android Studio) and debbug it in a separated thread, this functions start to work correctly and increases the route_id as expected. But only while debugging and repeating this instructions only:

db.beginTransaction();

```
    try {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FK_ROUTE_TRACK_ID, track_id);
        values.put(COL_ROUTE_ORDER, getLastOrderForTrack(track_id) + 1); 
        values.put(COL_ROUTE_LAT, latLongTime.getLatitude());
        values.put(COL_ROUTE_LONG, latLongTime.getLongitude());
        values.put(COL_ROUTE_SPEED, latLongTime.getSpeed());
        values.put(COL_ROUTE_TIME, latLongTime.getInstante());

        route_id = db.insert(TABLE_ROUTES, null, values);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.
It happens that I was defining SQLiteDatabase, as

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

With the same name (db) on every method (I have more than 20 methods).

Changing the name to dbt, for example, solve the problem and it this working now.

Since this is a local variable it should be used and destroyed after the method ends, but I don't know why, the computer was messing up.
It would be nice if someone could provide some explanation on this because I solved the problem but I just have a guess about what is going on and I'm not sure the reason why was not working.